# JMETER Test plan with multiple thread groups

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Can a jmeter test plan(JMX) with multiple thread groups have same name for all the thread groups and samplers inside??

What's the downside if we use this way

Answer (score 0):

There are no limitations when it comes to naming Thread Groups or Samplers, you can use the same label everywhere.

If needed you can trace down the problematic or failed [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) to this or that [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) by looking at `threadName` column of the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles).

The only potentially dangerous limitation I can think of is properly naming [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-transaction-controller)'s children as if it will differ from the transaction Controler's name followed by dash followed by zero-based index of the Sampler - JMeter will fail to properly calculate the throughput and you will be seeing extra sample results in i.e. [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

[image]